# Find a matrix $Q \in O_3(\mathbb{R})$, so that the matrix $Q^{-1}AQ$ has the diagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} \frac 58 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} & -\frac 34 \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} & \frac78 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \\ \frac34 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} & \frac 12 \end{pmatrix}$ $\in O_3(\mathbb{R})$, where $O_3(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \mid A^TA = E\}$.

Find a matrix $Q \in O_3(\mathbb{R})$, so that the matrix $Q^{-1}AQ$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix} A_1 &  &  \\  & \ddots &  \\  &  & A_t \end{pmatrix}$, where $A_i = (a_i)$, $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, or $A_i = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\varphi_i & -\sin\varphi_i \\ \sin\varphi_i & \cos\varphi_i\end{pmatrix}$, $\varphi_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i = 1, ..., t$.

First I tried to find the eigenvalues by computing the characteristic polynomial but I think it's the wrong way. How can I find a $Q$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is not the wrong way.

Comment: Hint: blocks of the second form correspond to complex conjugate eigenvalue pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is already orthogonal. Since the dimension ($3$) is odd, there is a real eigenvalue, call it $\lambda,$ and orthogonality means $\lambda = \pm 1.$ You can arrange that $\lambda $ be the $1,1$ entry. The special thing about dimension 3 is that we are rotating about this axis (the real eigenvector). By my count, the trace is $2,$ so, let's see, we should have $\lambda = +1.$ The other eigenvalues are complex conjugates, real part must be $+ \frac{1}{2},$ so these will be $\frac{1 \pm i \sqrt 3}{2}.$

Anyway, yes, go ahead, find the eigenvectors.

Comment: I have a question (Just for my own understanding about intuition  of eigenvalues ) :  How do you relate Eigenvalues to rotation ? is it true for any real matrix?

And also how do you guarantee that $Q$ coming from eigenvectors of$A$ does belong to   $O_3(\mathbb{R}) $? Thanks

Comment: @Ashkan all depends heavily on orthogonal matrix, including the outcome that the eigenvalues are of magnitude $1$ as complex numbers. If you construct the "axis," eigenvalue $1,$ and normalize it to length one, then take any unit vector perpendicular to that, then the cross product of the first two, it will all work out.

Comment: $\lambda$ = 1 and the eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{3} \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. If I normalize it, $v_1$ = $\begin{pmatrix} \frac12 \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}. v_1$ is one column of $Q$ and another column is any unit vector($v_2$) perpendicular to $v_1$ and the third colmun is the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$? Did I understand correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is orthogonal and $\det A=1$, so it represents a rotation. You can recover the axis of rotation by finding an eigenvector of $1$ and, if you like, the rotation angle $\theta$ by using $\operatorname{tr}A=1+2\cos\theta$, although that’s unnecessary for this problem. Once you have the rotation axis, finding $Q$ amounts to finding an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^3$ in which this rotation looks like a rotation about one of the coordinate axes (hint: one of the basis vectors will be a unit eigenvector of $1$).